# Z3: nonlinear arithmetic and quantifiers - wrong results?

Tags: z3

Here is a Z3 query that produces "sat" as result. (I am running Z3
Version 4.8.0, the results are identical in the rise4fun web
interface.)

```
(assert (forall ((x Real))
        (exists ((y Real))
                (and (<= 0.0 y) (<= y 1.0) (<= x (* y y))))))
(check-sat)
```

However, this formula should be unsatisfiable! Not every real number
is smaller or equal than the square of a number between 0 and 1.

The result changes if I reorder the formulas in the conjunction:

```
(assert (forall ((x Real))
        (exists ((y Real))
                (and (<= x (* y y)) (<= 0.0 y) (<= y 1.0)))))
(check-sat)
```

Then I get "unsat", which is fine.

If I switch on proof generation, then I obtain "unknown", which is at
least sound.

```
(set-option :produce-proofs true)

(assert (forall ((x Real))
        (exists ((y Real))
                (and (<= 0.0 y) (<= y 1.0) (<= x (* y y))))))
(check-sat)
```

Can somebody give me a clue what is going on? Did I overlook something
or is it a bug?

Comment: This is now marked as a bug in the Z3 issue tracker: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1658

Comment: This is now fixed in the master branch. (You'll have to build from sources!)

Answer (score 1):

Note: This was most definitely a bug at the point of reporting. It has since been fixed.